# Laravel assets return 404 on localhost

Tags: php, css, laravel-5, assets

I am pretty new to Laravel. I use Ubuntu and cloned an app from GitHub on home folder. When I run the app with `php artisan serve` I don't see the page styled. `Ctrl-u` shows the source with no problem but I have 404 errors in the console regarding everything under the asset folder.
[console warnings can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG0dP.png)

my 000_default.conf file is

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-defult.conf                 
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot ~/_/www/easymove/public

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/laravel>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Contents of the `webpack.mix.js` at the app root are as follows:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Have you compiled your assets? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix

Comment: Yes I have. I ran the commands : `npm run dev` and `npm run production`

Comment: In that case, you will need to update your question, providing more information on:

1. What you have done
2. What errors your are experiencing (Be precise)
3. Where your assets are stored, the contents of your mix files, and where the assets (compiled) are after running the mix.

Comment: Would these suffice? Is there anything else that I can provide?

Comment: Perfect! I'm not seeing anything in your webmix for compiling images. So you have 2 options. Move them into the relevant directories in `public` yourself, or create some additional Webpack rules to do this for you. Docs are in the same link I gave you above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some rules to your webpack.mix.js to handle your assets.

At current, your webpack will only compile JS files. You need to have it also copy over files and directories for your images and compile your css based on where its currently residing:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#copying-files-and-directories

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#working-with-stylesheets